# jQuery scrolling to div then expose

Tags: jquery, scrollto

I want to scroll to a div then when it reaches the div highlight it using expose.

At the moment I can get the scroll to work on its own, and the expose on its own but struggling to get them together.

What I have so far:

```
$(function() {

  $("a.link").click(function() {

$.scrollTo('#test', 800);

  $("#test").expose();

  });

});
```

Comment: When you use some plugins you found *"out there"* you're rolling dices to get some answers. Rather setup a demo jsBin or jsFiddle with the plugin included.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("a.link").click(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     var $test = $('#test'), o = $test.offset().top;
     $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: o }, 800, function(){
         $test.expose();
     })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

the scrollto function has a setting for a function to execute when the scrolling complete. do the expose in that function.

```
$.scrollTo('#test', 800, {
  'onAfter': function() {
    $("#test").expose();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

this is because.. `expose` is called before the `scroll` is taking place... use `onAfter` options...this function is called after scrolling ends

> onAfter: called after the scrolling ends

```
$.scrollTo('#test', 800, {onAfter:function(){ $("#test").expose(); } } );
```